# Ansible: force installing latest nodejs package

Tags: node.js, vagrant, ansible, virtualbox, apt

I don't understand why Ansible is installing an old version of nodejs even though I set it to install latest:

```
- name: NodeJS => Install NodeJS
  apt:
      pkg: "{{ item }}"
      state: latest
      force: yes
      update_cache: yes
  with_items:
    - nodejs
    - npm
  become: yes

- name: NodeJS => Create link symlink for node
  become: yes
  file:
    src: /usr/bin/nodejs
    dest: /usr/bin/node
    state: link
```

For the current versions I have now:

```
$ node -v
v0.10.25

$ npm -v
1.3.10
```

## Updated solution

I finally did this in my task/main.yml

```
---
- name: Ensure apt-transport-https is installed.
  apt: name=apt-transport-https state=present

- name: Add Nodesource apt key.
  become: yes
  apt_key:
    url: https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&fingerprint=on&search=0x1655A0AB68576280
    id: "68576280"
    state: present

- name: Add NodeSource repositories for Node.js.
  become: yes
  apt_repository:
    repo: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_{{ params['nodejs'].version }} {{ ansible_distribution_release }} main"
#    - "deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_{{ params['nodejs'].version }} {{ ansible_distribution_release }} main"
  register: node_repo

- name: Update apt cache if repo was added.
  become: yes
  apt: update_cache=yes
  when: node_repo.changed

- name: Ensure Node.js and npm are installed.
  become: yes
  apt: "name=nodejs={{ params['nodejs'].version|regex_replace('x', '') }}* state=present"
```

Comment: ansible will take the latest from the repo, what is your vagrant box ?

Comment: config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to first setup the ppa repository for the nodejs branch you want to install, for example for the 6.x branch (change if you want the 7.x branch)

```
- apt_repository:
    repo: deb https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x nodejs
    state: present
```

Then you will be able to install node and npm.

Comment: Is there any possibility to update to the latest without specifying the version?

Comment: not really, as the repo from this version is pretty old, you need to update the repo, and nodejs maintains the repo this way